# jQuery (mobile) not triggering .change event on Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery

(because 2 days I had no issues with this...)

I have a multipage layout, in one of my pages I have a structure like so:

```
<div id="view_offer" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Edit Offer</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p><label><input id="auto_renew" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0">Auto renew?</label></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the following scripts (in this order) before I close the body tag:

```
    <script src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home_m_scripts.js"></script>
```

My **home_m_scripts.js** file:

```
$("#auto_renew").change(function(){
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

My change event is not triggering though, I'm at loss here.

Comment: Can you change it to this: $(document).on('change','#auto_renew',function(){
    alert("Changed!");
});

Comment: This worked, I find it strange though, I might have a totally bad idea on jquerymobile, but I thought everything loaded as we land on a new page...

Comment: I will put it as an answer with a description

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
$("#auto_renew").change(function(){
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

To:

```
$(document).on('change','#auto_renew',function(){ 
    alert("Changed!"); 
});
```

When you bind an event like this it will act as an event delegation. Basically object don't need to exist in a DOM when you execute this binding.

Comment: How can I target a new div inside the .on event though? Imagining I have a "#stuff" div just under "#auto_renew", how can I do something like $("#stuff").html("stuff"); , this jquery mobile page structure is confusing as hell.

Comment: Got it, for example if you have an event on an id auto_renew and want to do something on a child div with an id stuff you would do it like this $(this).find('#stuff')... or you can do it like this: $('#auto_renew').find('#stuff') or even like this $('#auto_renew #stuff')