# jquery mobile slider event not detected in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to get on/off events for a slider widget in my mobile application.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTjtt/4/)

```
var val = 'on';
$('select#flag').change(function() {
    if(val!==$(this).val()){
        alert($(this).val());
    }
    val = $(this).val();
});
```

which works fine but not on my mobile using cordova/phonegap 3.5 and JqueryMobile.

- Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with the default browser of your phone? Usually the cause is not cordova but android's default browser. As Cordova uses a webview, it's powered by the default browser and it's a pain for many other things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When you bind an event like this it will act as an event delegation.  Basically object don't need to exist in a DOM when you execute this binding.*

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948579/1948785) and copied its explanation, it solves my problem getting the event.