# jQuery .change() event not working on mobile with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using ui-autocomplete in a text box. Once they select an autocomplete drop down and leave that text box it auto populates all other text fields. All of this works on a pc, but does not work on a mobile webpage. I've come to find out it has something to do with the ui-autocomplete plugin, it won't let the mobile browser pick up the change event.

I've looking over similar cases but can't seem to resolve the issue. I'm very new to jQuery

If I un-comment the last plugin, the change event will be picked up but the auto-fill will not work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
```

Text box:

```
<tr><td>Part Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="PartNum" class="auto" id="pn" style="width:250px" required></td></tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $(".auto").autocomplete({
                    source: "autocomplete.php",
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Change event

```
$('#pn').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myrequest();
    });
```

Again, this works on pc fine but wont work on mobile. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you importing/inserting jquery so many times? if last line is un-commented it will be 3 different version of Jquery included in your page... all conflicting with each other. you just need one Jquery and one jqueryUi

Comment: Noted. I edited the code, but I'm still in the same predicament. If I un-comment the last one and take out the first one, the change event works on mobile but not the autocomplete.

Comment: 2 reasons behind it. First the version numbers. The first instance is old one 1.9, and the last instance is latest 3.4. Secondly, you HAVE to have Jquery inserted before JqueryUI as it is dependent on Jquery. Move the last line before the jqueryui and disable older version.

Comment: I edited the code again, the autocomplete is working with the updated jquery now (with different formatting), but the autofill of the other text boxes still isn't working on mobile.

Comment: *the change event still is not being recognized on mobile

Comment: Maybe the even delegation is the issue here. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948353/jquery-mobile-not-triggering-change-event-on-phonegap-app

Comment: I saw that article earlier and it didn't change the effect, I actually got it working, but not the way I hope for. When I select from the autocomplete drop down on pc I can go to the next line and the event will be triggered, on mobile I can select the DD but I have to physically type something (e.g. hitting the space bar) then go to the next line for it to work..

Comment: Better than not working at all.. thank you for your help in the matter. If you think you have a solution to this problem I'm all ears, otherwise thank you.

Comment: JQueryui autocomplete has a select() event that is triggered when something is selected. You should not be doing a .change() on the field. https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: I saw this as well but wasn't sure how to properly apply it to my code. I tried a few times to incorporate it but it wouldn't function.

Answer (score 1):

The JQueryUI Autocomplete has a select() event that is triggered when an item is selected. It is better to use that because .change() first of all works when user focuses out on the element, secondly when autocomplete is created on an input field the field itself is replaced (and is hidden).

This is how you would implement the select() event:

```
$(function() {
   $(".auto").autocomplete({
      source: "autocomplete.php",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) { myrequest(); }
   });
});
```

You do not need a preventdefault here. you can add more code within the function braces.

Comment: I'm at a loss.. I added it in but it won't let me click on a drop down, I have to use the arrow keys for it to take, and then hitting enter still doesn't take away all the options. I'm sorry I'm just not proficient in jQuery.

Comment: I added a focus event to the succeeding box and that works much better, as that text box is required any way, the auto-fill will take place.

Comment: Does the simple autocomplete work for you the way you want? Visit https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ on mobile and see if that works for you. I suspect your understanding of the tool is different than what it really does. Secondly what is myrequest() doing? comment out the select: functio... line and see if the autocomplete is doing what it is supposed to do. Deal these 2 issues separately. Autocomplete functionality and the select/change functionality.

Comment: myrequest is the portion of the code that populates text boxes based on returned values from ajax/json, based on the autocomplete value the user entered. The autocomplete is doing exactly what I want. It may not be perfect as far as efficiency goes with the way I have (I really don't know I'm just assuming), but everything is working as I had intended it to.